# Integer through socket - wrong bytes

Tags: java, android, network-programming, tcl

I'm sending an integer from Tcl script running on my PC to Java application, that is running on Android.

Tcl code:

```
set bytes 10
set sock [socket localhost $port]
set binLen [binary format i $bytes]
puts "Sending size: $bytes"
puts $sock $binLen
flush $sock
close $sock
```

Java code reading it on Android side:

```
Socket clientSocket = ...; // socket created for connected Tcl script
InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
byte[] sizeBuffer = new byte[4];
dataInputStream.readFully(sizeBuffer);
```

Now, when I preview the `sizeBuffer` in debug, I see that it's:

```
sizeBuffer = {byte[4]@830050199072}
[0] = 13
[1] = 10
[2] = 0
[3] = 0
```

This doesn't seem quite right. Leter on I want to convert it back to integer with:

```
int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(sizeBuffer).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
```

but it gives 2573, not 10, which is obvious according to received bytes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Obvious? Then what is 13 doing?

Comment: On the other hand, 10 and 13 are the decimal values of `\n` and `\r`

Comment: Yes, but who is sending them?

Comment: Why not `puts $sock $bytes` ?

Comment: I don't know tcl, but any chance there's some ASCII mode transfer going on? Can you try a different number than 10?

Comment: puts == put string? Is there put?

Comment: [`puts`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm) writes a new line.

Comment: @ci_, Sotirios, you are both right. The socket in Tcl should be configured to binary mode. I'll fix it and test the solution ASAP.

Comment: use `puts -nonewline $sock $binLen`

Comment: You should be using `DataInputStream.readInt()` instead of all that byte-handling code. You then have to ensure that the sender sends the integer in network byte order (big-endian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you've got is that `puts` appends a newline sequence by default (because it's first job is writing out text for people to read). Your platform's default newline sequence is carriage-return/newline. When writing binary, you should do two things: put the channel in binary mode, and not write extra line terminators.

```tcl
# Put the channel in binary mode
fconfigure $sock -translation binary
```

```tcl
# Write without extra bytes
puts -nonewline $sock $binLen
```